# Advice for going from CSV > JSON > Swift objects

Tags: json, csv

New to programming, hoping I can get some advice on the best way to approach this.

I have a CSV file with data I need to convert to custom objects in Swift. The custom type is mostly made up of `String` and `[String]` properties.

I was told working with CSVs is difficult, especially if my data contains special characters (it does), and I'd have more flexibility using JSON. So I converted the CSV to JSON using an online tool, imported it, and attempted to decode it.

The issue is, the CSV cells that need to become `[String]` aren't formatted as arrays in the CSV. They're just values separated by commas or line breaks, so the online tool interprets the whole cell as being one long string.

So basically, I need a way to convert those cells into arrays. The question is, is that best done to the CSV before converting to JSON? Or to the JSON before or after decoding? Or perhaps I should make an intermediate object type with just strings, convert the string properties to arrays, and then create a new object of the correct type?

Or is there some better method to all of this?

Comment: My suggestion is, prepare the JSON before you decode it to Swift's type. If you plan to modify the object after decoding, you have to handle various unrelated cases. Also the latter is likely to be broken from time to time. So better you finalize the JSON as your need and then just do the decoding part in Swift.

Comment: Thanks @nayem. Can you recommend the best approach for that? At the moment Swift is the only language I know. Sorry for the really basic questions.

Comment: Haven't you said that you used an online tool? Use that tool's output JSON and manually update the JSON as your need (where you need to have `[String]`). But if you need the tool, here is one: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

Comment: Yes I've been using that site but I need an automated solution, as I'll need to do this again when I get new CSVs. Maybe I'll experiment with decoding the JSON to a simple dictionary, use replacingOccurrences(of:) to try and create the arrays, and encode back to a JSON, before trying to decode it again into my custom type.